# In a class that derives a List<>, how to access the list

Tags: c#, .net

This question is messed up
See bottom

In ResultsB how do I access List?

```
public class ResultsB : List<ResultB>
{
    public string Methods
    {
        get
        {
            // what I want is 
            return string.Join(", ", this);
            // and have this be List<ResultB> 
            // this fails
            // it returns "PuzzleBinarySearchWeighted.Program+ResultB, PuzzleBinarySearchWeighted.Program+ResultB" 
            // I just get information about the object 
            // this fails also - same thing information about the object 
            //return string.Join(", ", this.GetEnumerator());
        }
    }
    public void testEnum()
    {  
        // this works
        foreach (ResultB resultB in this)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(resultB.MethodsString);
        }
    }
}
```

Externally I can do this -

```
 ResultsB resultsB = new ResultsB();
 resultsB.Add(new ResultB(1, "a:b"));
 resultsB.Add(new ResultB(2, "c:b"));
```

I was just looking at this wrong
I needed an iEnumerable the from all List
I cannot delete as an answer has up votes
Sorry -  I VTC and request you do the same

```
public string Methods
{
    get
    {
        return string.Join(", ", this.MethodsAll);
    }
}
public HashSet<string> MethodsAll
{
    get
    {
        HashSet<string> hs = new HashSet<string>();
        foreach (ResultB resultB in this)
        {
            foreach (string s in resultB.Methods)
            {
                hs.Add(s);
            }
        }
        return hs;
    }
}
```

Comment: You use the `base` keyword.

Comment: Why are you deriving from `List<T>`? You should prefer composition over inheritance. Also your posting says "implement" but `List<T>` is a class, not an interface.

Comment: Please define *fails*. Elaborate more on this, provide the exception... stacktrace

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer will update

Comment: *"it returns "PuzzleBinarySearchWeighted.Program+ResultB..."* - and what do you expect it to return? You're trying to join a list of objects as a string. This problem has nothing to do with the fact that you're deriving from `List<T>`.

Comment: @AntP I get ambiguous calls between params object[] and iEnumerable<t>

Comment: @Paparazzi But you could resolve your own question dropping the noise and leaving just as you asked it first, and then you can select my answer. I see that your own answer inside the question is what I've already answered you (the use of `this`), isn't it?

Comment: @Paparazzi So I can drop the `string.Join` part. Do you agree my argument? ;P

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Close enough.  I was asking the wrong question.

Comment: @Paparazzi BTW, AFAIK you can delete a question even if it has already received an answer.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer It tells me that it needs a mod to delete.

Comment: @Paparazzi Oops, I thought you had the whole button but once you could click it, it would say something like you couldn't do that action many times or your account could get blocked...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implicitly with `this`.

For example, calling `Add` as follows `Add("hello world")` which implicitly is `this.Add("hello world")`:

```
public class CustomListOfStrings : List<string>
{
      // ...
      private void DoStuff() 
      {
            Add("Whatever");
      }
}
```

@Paparazzi commented out:

> I should have been more clear I need a foreach

`this` keyword to the rescue!

```
foreach(ResultB result in this)
{

}
```

### OP wants to use `string.Join` directly

OP has edited the question and says that wants to use `string.Join` as follows:

`string.Join(", ", this)`.

The `string.Join` overload that you can use is [`string.Join(string, IEnumerable<T>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx), and it'll call `Object.ToString` on each object found in the given sequence (i.e. `IEnumerable<T>`). So you need to provide an overridden `Object.ToString` method in your result class (you can check that on [Reference Source for `string.Join`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,da0d95b54df01dcf)):

```
public class ResultB
{
     public override string ToString()
     {
           // You need to provide what would be a string representation
           // of ResultB
           return "Who knows what you want to return here";
     }
}
```

...and your code will work as you expect!

Comment: Please see my revision.  I which to access in a String.Join.

Comment: @Paparazzi Now? :D

Comment: @Paparazzi See my re-edited answer and let me know if it has already solved your issue

Comment: My question is a big messed up right now.  Let be try and get it cleaned up.

Comment: @Paparazzi Ok, in the mean time, I'm going to wash the dishes lol